# How to use Dispatcher.PushFrame before the Window is loaded?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a function where I must **synchronously** wait for user input. I have no control over from which thread this function is called, so it could be that the caller is already at the UI thread or not (in this case, I would have to use the Dispatcher).

To this to work I've been using `DispatcherFrame` and `Dispatcher.PushFrame`, so that the UI continues to respond, even if the funcion is called from the UI thread.

Here's a small demo (please note that this is a very dumb example, but that represent what I'm trying to achive):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Width="500">
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Result"
             Margin="0 0 0 10" />

    <Button x:Name="Button_ContinueExecution"
            Content="..." />
</StackPanel>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
string PromptUserForInputSynchronously()
{
    string result = null;

    if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        var nestedFrame = new DispatcherFrame(true);

        Button_ContinueExecution.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            nestedFrame.Continue = false;
            result = TextBox_Result.Text;
        };

        Button_ContinueExecution.Content = "Click to resume execution";

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for click...");

        Dispatcher.PushFrame(nestedFrame);

        Console.WriteLine("Clicked with text: " + result);
    }
    else
    {
        result = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => PromptUserForInputSynchronously());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, this *appears* to work, except when (I guess) the MainWindow haven't loaded yet. Take a look:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // This works
    Loaded += (s, e) => PromptUserForInputSynchronously();

    // This hangs the application
    PromptUserForInputSynchronously();
}
```

Is there any way I can make this work? Is this the best approach?

**@edit: Background**

What I'm trying to achive is to create a dialog that acts like a `MessageBox` (but looks nicer). When shown, the dialog blocks the current thread (but keeps the UI responsive in case this thread is the Dispatcher one) until the user clicks on one of the buttons.

My goal was to later provide this in the form of a NuGet package, which is why I was testing it in different scenarios (like calling it from inside the constructor).

Comment: You shouldn't interrupt processing of any constructor. That's a bad idea. The mainwindow is a particularly bad object to choose to interrupt during it's construction. As to what would be better. I don't follow what it's supposd to do. If it's not supposed to block processing then why not just a window? If it's supposed to block processing then a modal dialogue?

Comment: How can the user interact with the UI when it is not loaded?

Comment: @Andy I wish I didn't have to create a Window for this, but using `ShowDialog` (I assume this is what you meant by “modal dialogue”, am I correct?) does seem to be a better option (although, under the hood, this method seems to be doing something similar to what I was trying to do)

Comment: @BionicCode Exactly, but I thought that using the `DispatcherFrame` would allow the Window to load and _then_ wait for user input

Comment: Glossing over details. Mainwindow is instantiated by your entry point. The dispatcher is started up by the entry point. No dispatcher means trying to use it will of course error. But that's neither here nor there. I still don't understand what it is you're aiming to achieve but one thing I can tell you for sure.  The whole idea of showing some other UI from the constructor of a window is a bad idea.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the info! Do you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it? Also, I added a bit more info about what I'm trying to achieve at the end of the post, in case it is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code throws an error will be because the Dispatcher hasn't been started up at that point. By default your entry point will be instantiating MainWindow to show it.  The exact details aren't something I've ever found a use for, but, the Dispatcher is also started up. Clearly, that doesn't happen until after mainwindow is instantiated.

You therefore would have to change some start up fundamentals to get this "working".

You could override app startup and try to ensure the sta thread and the dispatcher are going before you instantiate mainwindow. This is a bad idea though.

You should not try and do anything but instantiation in the mainwindow constructor. The reason being that if you get any error in that you have no main window at all. Your app will just shut down and your users will start complaining.

I would advise you extend this principle to any and all wpf windows. Minimise what you do in their constructors. Don't interrupt instantiation and in particular, do not try to show some other window from the ctor of a window.

If you need to throw up a message or get some user input before showing a window then just do that first and separately. If you need to show a window with a modal dialogue then show the window first and use a later event to drive your dialogue - showing.